# IndexError: index 26345 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 256 (Python, Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the value of Phi_s in the code given below and everytime it is giving me an error like one mentioned in the title. The code is given below:

```
M1=8
M2=8
N1=16
N2=16
M=M1*M2 
N=N1*N2 
K=16    

L1=5    
L2=8    

L2c1=4

Hhat=np.zeros((K,N,M),dtype=complex)
T=np.size(A,0)
e=0
for k in range(K):
    Yk = Y[k,:,:]
    s = np.absolute(Yk)
    s = np.square(s)
    s = np.sum(s,axis=0)
    e = e + s
index=e.argsort()[::-1]
column=index[0:L1]
Full_Supports = np.zeros((K,L1,L2),dtype=complex)

for c in range(L1):
    Yc=Y[:,:,column[c]]
    Yc=np.reshape(Yc,(T,K))
    Rc=Yc
    rowc=[]
    Hchat=np.zeros((N,K),dtype=complex)
    if L2c1>0:
        FullRow=np.zeros((L2,K),dtype=complex)
        for k in range(K):
            k
            yc=Yc[:,k]  
            rc=Rc[:,k]  
            row=[]
            for r in range(L2):
                e=np.square(np.absolute(np.matmul(A.T,rc)))
                index=np.argmax(e) 
                row.append(index)
                Phi_s=A[:,row]
```

Writing this code produces a very vague error which is given below:

```
File "e:\Saarthak\PROJECT WORK\RIS\dsomp2.py", line 116, in <module>
    Phi_s=A[:,row]        
IndexError: index 26345 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 256
```

Comment: Array A does not have column number 26345. Since you do not show how the array was created, we cannot advise how to fix it.

Comment: please (always) post *full* error trace, not just the last line